# Bone copy location in some keyframes

Tags: keyframes

How can I make a bone to copy a location of another bone but only in some specific keyframes and in other keyframes not to copy?
I have tried in blender 2.79 but the only option that I get is either the bone copy the location on all the animation or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pose mode, assign a copy location constraint to the bone that should move, and set as target the other bone. Then you can Keyframe the "Influence" parameter to have the constraint working only in the desired keyframes.

Comment: Then you can upvote the answer, so it can be useful for other users!